# ExceptionInInitializerError in Telegram Bot

Tags: java, telegram-bot

I wrote a very simple telegram bot by java in Eclipse ide and there is no error in my code.
But after running the program it gives these errors! what does that mean?

```
Exception in thread "main" com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionError: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2205)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:3953)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.getOrLoad(LocalCache.java:3957)

...

Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerErrorat com.google.inject.internal.cglib.reflect.$FastClass$Generator.getProtectionDomain(FastClass.java:73)
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:206)
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.reflect.$FastClass$Generator.create(FastClass.java:65)
    at com.google.inject.internal.BytecodeGen.newFastClassForMember(BytecodeGen.java:252)
    at com.google.inject.internal.BytecodeGen.newFastClassForMember(BytecodeGen.java:203)
    at com.google.inject.internal.DefaultConstructionProxyFactory.create(DefaultConstructionProxyFactory.java:53)
...

Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make protected final java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain) throws java.lang.ClassFormatError accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to unnamed module @56de5251
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:357)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:297)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.checkCanSetAccessible(Method.java:199)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.setAccessible(Method.java:193)
```

(The error is longer)
Also I have to mention that I use proxy for telegram..

Comment: Hi Harmonic, are you able to provide details of any libraries you are using and maybe a code sample?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.